# Use Kubectl Apply command using k8s.io package

Tags: go, kubernetes

I need to add `kubectl apply` functionality to my application.

I've looked through `kubectl go-client`, it has no provisions for the apply command.

1. Can I create an instance of `kubectl` in my go-application?
2. If not 1, can I use the `k8s.io/kubernetes` package to emulate an `kubectl apply` command?

Questions and clarifications if needed, will be given.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Can I create an instance of kubectl in my application?

You can wrap the `kubectl` command in your application and start it in a new child-process, like you would do via a shell-script. See the `exec` package in go for more information: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/

This works pretty good for us and kubectl usually has the `-o`-Parameter that lets you control the output format, so you get machine readable text back.

There are already some open-source projects that use this approach:

- https://github.com/box/kube-applier
- https://github.com/autoapply/autoapply

> 2. If not 1, can I use the k8s.io/kubernetes package to emulate an kubectl apply command?

Have you found https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/apply/apply.go while searching in kubectl-source code?
Take a look at the run-function:

```
func (o *ApplyOptions) Run() error {
    ...
    r := o.Builder.
        Unstructured().
        Schema(o.Validator).
        ContinueOnError().
        NamespaceParam(o.Namespace).DefaultNamespace().
        FilenameParam(o.EnforceNamespace, &o.DeleteOptions.FilenameOptions).
        LabelSelectorParam(o.Selector).
        IncludeUninitialized(o.ShouldIncludeUninitialized).
        Flatten().
        Do()
    ...
    err = r.Visit(func(info *resource.Info, err error) error {
    ...
```

It is not very good readable it guess but this is what `kubectl apply` does.
Maybe one possible way of whould be to debug the code and see what is does further more.

Comment: 1. I am not supposed to use an external dependency.
2. I am using v1.10.3, my apply.go looks a bit different. Nevertheless, replicating the process isn't something I'm looking for... Other suggestions, idea?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you exactly mean with: "I am not supposed to use an external dependency". Does this mean no "kubectl" call in your program, or no "exec"?

Comment: If so, you could use your languages features and call the kubenetes-api directly (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) and then create the apply-logic yourself (https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples/create-update-delete-deployment). It depends on your actual requirements. Something like `createOrUpdate` for specific resources could definitely be done with this client libraries. You can also get the current resources as JSON and compare them to only update differences ...

Comment: I am not supposed to use `os.exec`. About implementing the apply-logic using `CreateOrUpdate` is something I thought of too. Was looking for maybe something better, because I don't want the `apply` command to be restricted to a few chosen resources only.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by created and adding a plugin to kubectl.

> You can write a plugin in any programming language or script that allows you to write command-line commands.
>
> There is no plugin installation or pre-loading required. Plugin executables receive the inherited environment from the  `kubectl`  binary. A plugin determines which command path it wishes to implement based on its name. For example, a plugin wanting to provide a new command  `kubectl foo`, would simply be named  `kubectl-foo`, and live somewhere in the user’s PATH.

Example plugin can look as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
# optional argument handling
if [[ "$1" == "version" ]]
then
  echo "1.0.0"
  exit 0
fi

# optional argument handling
if [[ "$1" == "config" ]]
then
  echo $KUBECONFIG
  exit 0
fi
echo "I am a plugin named kubectl-foo"
```

After that you just make it executable `chmod +x ./kubectl-foo` and move it for in your path `mv ./kubectl-foo /usr/local/bin`.

Now you should be able to call it by `kubectl foo`:

```
$ kubectl foo
I am a plugin named kubectl-foo
```

All args and flags are passed as-is to the executable:

```
$ kubectl foo version
1.0.0
```

You can read more about the kubectl plugins inside Kubernetes [Extend kubectl with plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/) documentation.

Comment: the question would be if it's possible to invoke apply from the plugin itself

Answer (score 0):

- `kubectl` is supposed to be used from command line only
- but you can wraped it around inside the code using some form of exec such `os.system` in python , similar will exist in golang `import "os/exec`", but this approach is dirty
- you need to use the client libary in your code to carry out the operations
- list of client libraries is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/)

Comment: I have mentioned, I'm familiar with the `kubernetes go-client`. I don't want the dirty approach as it violates the [12 Factor app](https://12factor.net/)

Comment: *OffTopic*: It would be nice if you could mention which part of the **12 Factor app manifesto** the *dirty* approach would violate.

Comment: It gues all options are mentioned in this thread here. As there is no easy way to create a `kubectl apply` functionality in a client library, you could either use `kubectl` (via a plugin or directly) (see: https://github.com/box/kube-applier and https://github.com/box/kube-applier as existing references) or use a client-library and create the logic yourself. The client-libraries provide you all the methods that are necessary to do that, however it would be still quite some work. If you could for the latter it would be nice to share your solutions here and in some open source place.